# Laravel datatables not returning html link

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following function

```
public function getTasks()
    {
      $users = User::select(['id','users_full_names', 'email', 'users_telephone_number', 'users_credits', 'users_last_seen_carbon_object','users_profile_picture','updated_at']);

        return Datatables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($user) {
                return '<a href="/edit/'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a> <a href="/delete/'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a> <a href="/moderate/'.$user->emp_no.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> Moderate</a> <a href="/view/'.$user->emp_no.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> View</a> <a href="/impersonate/'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Impersonate</a>';
            })->editColumn('updated_at', function(User $user) {
              $dt = $user->updated_at->toDateTimeString();
              $datetime = Carbon::parse($dt);;
                    return $datetime->diffForHumans();
                })->editColumn('users_profile_picture', function(User $user) {
                  $picture = $user->users_profile_picture;
                        return '<a  href="'.url('uploads/'.$picture).'">View Image</a>';
                    })->make(true);
    }
```

that i am using to get the pictures stored in the database. This is the particular section that is creating the link

```
->editColumn('users_profile_picture', function(User $user) {
                  $picture = $user->users_profile_picture;
                        return '<a  href="'.url('uploads/'.$picture).'">View Image</a>';
                    })->make(true);
```

but the link generated looks like this

```
<a href="http://198.74.51.225/uploads/1494677997.79843.jpg">View Image</a>
```

instead of a clickable html link.

How can i fix this?.

Comment: You mean the href tag appears in view?

Comment: Looks like it is generating what you needed which should work without any issues. Do you mean it prints <a href="http://198.74.51.225/uploads/1494677997.79843.jpg">View Image</a> on your page instead of 'View Image' as a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use rawColumns as used below,

```
->editColumn('users_profile_picture', function(User $user) {
              $picture = $user->users_profile_picture;
                    return '<a  href="'.url('uploads/'.$picture).'">View Image</a>';
                })->rawColumns(['users_profile_picture'])->make(true);
```

Please refer, https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/949